# Redis Sorted Set ZSCAN with temporary set - a good idea?

Tags: redis, sortedset

The use case is very simple.

Say I have a zSet called "Employee" with values like so

```
zAdd Employee 1000 "Eric Anderson"
zAdd Employee 1200 "Eric Henderson"
zAdd Employee 1400 "Eric Johnson"
zAdd Employee 1500 "Jackie Johnson"
zAdd Employee 1600 "John Ericson"
```

So basically, if I wanted to have a function for users of the system to **wildcard search** for Employees, showing the result ordered by the score (highest to lowest), can I solve that with ZSCAN?

What I would like to do is something like this

```
ZSCAN Employee MATCH "*ohn*" LIMIT 0, 20
```

and get a result set like so

```
John Ericson, 1600
Jackie Johnson, 1500
Eric Johnson, 1400
```

leaving the other two since they don't match the search phrase "ohn".

In other words, this is BASIC search functionality. One which you could liken to

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE name LIKE "%ohn%" ORDER BY salary
```

In the above select, salary is the score value, obviously. The above query with LIKE and % % is obviously not advisable since it will not use index and will thereby filesort.

Please advice.

Edit: I forgot to add a suggested solution where you perform a regular ZSCAN that gets all values matching the search phrase, in whatever order I can't figure out, and then put those in a new zSET and perform a zREVRANGE on it, to get the results, and then remove that zSet. That's what I can think of will actually work, but is it advisable?

Comment: did you figure out this ? I'm looking for something similar

Comment: I've got to come clean and admit I can't remember since it was a while ago since I asked this question. I'm really sorry.